# Retrieving the correct data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a student report management System

In the system there are  4 tables;

1. **Students** table which stores student information like student name, student id etc.
2. **Marks** table which stores the marks of each student in each subject, this table links to the following tables;

   students table->(student_id), subjects table->(subject_id),class table->(class_table)and teacher table->(teacher_id)

The marks table table looks like this:

[image: table structure]

I want to be able to retrieve data from the linked tables and then for mark_1, I want to retrieve the mark for the student for that particular subject.

I currently have this code, what it does is that even if the student for example got 78% in History, the mark 78% will appear in all the subjects that child is doing,even if the child did not get 78%

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(marks.test_1),
    students.id,
    students.student_id,
    students.student_name,
    subjects.subject_name,
    forms.form_name,
    teacherxsubject.form_id,
    students.class,
    teacherxsubject.subject_id,
    teacherxsubject.teacher_id
FROM
    students
LEFT JOIN
    marks ON students.student_id = marks.student_id
LEFT JOIN
    teacherxsubject ON students.class = teacherxsubject.form_id
INNER JOIN
    subjects ON subjects.subject_id = teacherxsubject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN
    forms ON forms.form_id = teacherxsubject.form_id
LEFT JOIN 
    marks a ON marks.subject_id=subjects.subject_id
WHERE 
    teacherxsubject.teacher_id = 1200717 
    AND students.class = 6
```

Here is an example what the query returns:

[What the query returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gAec.jpg)

Comment: Pls include sample data for each table, expected results based on the sample data, and the actual results your query produces on the sample data.

Comment: @Shadow, I expect that when I retireve the data using the above query , the marks for the student for that particular subject will appear, not that if a student got 90 in Geography then that mark will also appear in biology,even if in biology there is no mark. I have edited the question to include the results of the mysql query

Comment: Pls provide the sample data because it is very difficult for us to understand what may have gone wrong.

Comment: Sample data as in the result of the above mentioned sql query?

Comment: @Neliza sample data, not the DDL though that is helpful. Ideally create some temp tables and insert some test data that we can use. i.e. `create table #temptTable (...) insert into #tempTable values (...),(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You join to the marks table twice...

```
LEFT JOIN
marks ON students.student_id = marks.student_id
```

First on student Id, leading to ALL marks for that student, then

```
LEFT JOIN 
marks a ON marks.subject_id=subjects.subject_id
```

then on subjectid, leading to all marks for that subject (for ALL students)...

You will want both in the one join;

```
LEFT JOIN
marks ON students.student_id = marks.student_id
AND marks.subject_id=subjects.subject_id
```

P.S. What is up with your data types? You have a 200 character string, 2 x 10 character strings, and an int...